Python executing print statements inside false ifs
salt = "Salt and Vinegar"
bland = "Saltenes"
sweet = "Chocolate"
spicy = "Takis"
sour = "Sour Patch Kids"
q1 = print(input("Do you want a bland or flavorful snack? "))
q2 = print(input("Do you want a sweeter or saltier snack? "))
q3 = print(input("Would you like a sour snack or not? "))
q4 = print(input("Would you like a spicy snack or not? "))
rec = ""

print(input("Do you want a bland or flavorful snack? "))
if q1 == "Bland":
   rec = bland
elif q1 == "Flavorful":
    print(input("Do you want a sweeter or saltier snack? "))
    if q2 == "Sweeter":
        print(input("Would you like a sour snack or not? "))
        if q3 == "Sour":
            rec = sour
        elif q3 == "Not":
            rec = sweet
    elif q2 == "Saltier":
        print(input("Would you like a spicy snack or not? "))
        if q4 == "Spicy":
            rec = spicy
        elif q4 =="Not":
            rec = salt

print("We recommend " + rec + " as your snack!")

My code looks like this. I'm having issues with it running, for example,  print(input("Do you want a sweeter or saltier snack? ")) even when the persons input was Bland, and, thus, shouldn't run the rest of the program.
I already made each question it's own variable and had all my final answers be variables. I'm relatively sure that the, for example, q1 == "Bland" using a string shouldn't ruin my code but it's very possible I'm wrong. I'm new to coding.

btw print(input( ...  is almost never what you want.

print(input()) doesn't actually capture the input to a variable, it just prints it to the console then discards it. instead q1 = input('blah')

This question is similar to: Why is "None" printed after my function's output?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@JonSG OP hasn't written a function, so that's not applicable, but I'm sure there's another question that is applicable.

Why did you duplicate the inputs? You have two problems here that are perfectly natural for new programmers (and maybe some sub-problems too), but it doesn't make any sense to duplicate the input calls, so you need to clear that up first. Please make a [mre]. In the process, you might actually find some solutions yourself :) BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and see [ask] for more tips, like how to write a good title.

@JonSG This might be what you wanted: Why does the print function return None?

BTW, to be pedantic, print is a function in Python 3, not a statement.

@wjandrea That is probably a better dupe, thanks. Though I feel the one I found still explains the issue.

You meant to assign variables to the result of calling input(), but within your if sections so that your program won't need to run some of them.
salt = "Salt and Vinegar"
bland = "Saltenes"
sweet = "Chocolate"
spicy = "Takis"
sour = "Sour Patch Kids"
rec = ""

q1 = input("Do you want a bland or flavorful snack? ")
if q1 == "Bland":
   rec = bland
elif q1 == "Flavorful":
    q2 = input("Do you want a sweeter or saltier snack? ")
    if q2 == "Sweeter":
        q3 = input("Would you like a sour snack or not? ")
        if q3 == "Sour":
            rec = sour
        elif q3 == "Not":
            rec = sweet
    elif q2 == "Saltier":
        q4 = input("Would you like a spicy snack or not? ")
        if q4 == "Spicy":
            rec = spicy
        elif q4 =="Not":
            rec = salt

print("We recommend " + rec + " as your snack!")

You don't need to use print() because the input() reflects what the user types.


Issue with your code is you're capturing multiple input from user without saving them that's why 2nd 3rd and 4th inputs are not used correctly in logic.
You need to store user input in variables and use them in the conditional flow.
Each input is handled based on the user's previous choices.
strip() :any extra whitespace, and convert it to lowercase to handle various input cases.
Lower(): case of entered string

Use Below Code
    # Define snack options
salt = "Salt and Vinegar"
bland = "Saltenes"
sweet = "Chocolate"
spicy = "Takis"
sour = "Sour Patch Kids"

# Ask user for their preferences
q1 = input("Do you want a bland or flavorful snack? (bland/flavorful) ").strip().lower()

if q1 == "bland":
    rec = bland
elif q1 == "flavorful":
    q2 = input("Do you want a sweeter or saltier snack? (sweeter/saltier) ").strip().lower()
    if q2 == "sweeter":
        q3 = input("Would you like a sour snack or not? (sour/not) ").strip().lower()
        if q3 == "sour":
            rec = sour
        elif q3 == "not":
            rec = sweet
        else:
            rec = "Sorry, I didn't understand your choice for sour or not."
    elif q2 == "saltier":
        q4 = input("Would you like a spicy snack or not? (spicy/not) ").strip().lower()
        if q4 == "spicy":
            rec = spicy
        elif q4 == "not":
            rec = salt
        else:
            rec = "Sorry, I didn't understand your choice for spicy or not."
    else:
        rec = "Sorry, I didn't understand your choice for sweeter or saltier."
else:
    rec = "Sorry, I didn't understand your choice for bland or flavorful."

print("We recommend " + rec + " as your snack!")

